# Apache running but not serving pages

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, not-responding

Everything was working just fine until i rebooted my server and now when I visit the page (with both apache and mysql running), I get the following:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to mydomain.com
```

Apache is confirmed to be running, as is MySQL.

The `/var/log/httpd/error_log` looks as follows:

```
[Tue Nov 22 10:06:05 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Nov 22 10:06:05 2011] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Nov 22 10:06:05 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Nov 22 10:06:05 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Nov 22 10:06:05 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I believe the `caught SIGTERM, shutting down` is when i performed `service httpd restart`

Again -- server, apache, and MySQL are up and running, only using 7% of disk space, but I cannot get it to serve any pages. I haven't touched the httpd.conf file any time recently so I'm not sure what is going on.

Also, apache restarts just fine given its config file. The configuration points to the correct directory as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you access the server locally? It can be a network problem. Also, make sure the server is listening on the port 80 by using `netstat -lnp`.

Comment: Yes, check my answer -- i had an issue with firewalls blocking. I disabled them but I'm not sure of the proper solution to keep the firewalls up but allow access to :80

Answer (score 4):

Ah -- i had firewalls blocking my port

`iptables -F` has cleared the problem, but I am assuming is definitely not a proper fix.

Comment: Yeah this aint a proper fix.